# print something when input isn't something specified

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry for the horrible question. Basically, I am making the Yes or No game in Python and I need it to print something e.g. "You Win" if they input something from a library that I have already made with every acceptable word. TY in advance

```
q1 = input ("Answer: ")

while q1 == "yes" or "Yes" or "no" or "No":
    print ("Sorry but you answered \"" + q1 + "\" which means you lose!")
    sys.exit ("\nGame Over")
if q1 == ###:
    print ("Well done you have earned yourself a point")
    score +=1
    print ("Your current score is: " + score)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_word = input('Insert a word: ')
list_of_acceptable_words = ['word1', 'word2']
if input_word in list_of_acceptable_words:
    print('You Win')
```

Where `input_word` is a string containing the input from the user and `list_of_acceptable_words` is a list of acceptable words

Answer (score 0):

You can probably start out from this snippet, using the built-in set type:

```
>>> lib={'Alice','Bob'}
>>> print('Bob' in lib)
True
>>> print('Carol' in lib)
False
```

Then one can add a bit of code around to match your needs more closely:

```
>>> guess='Dave'
>>> print(['You lose...', 'You WIN!'][guess in lib])
You lose...
>>> guess='Alice'
>>> print(['You lose...', 'You WIN!'][guess in lib])
You WIN!
```

Edit: now that you have updated your OP with some snippet, I can write some code more in line with your needs.

```
accepted=set(line.strip() for line in open('accepted.txt'))

q1 = input("Answer: ")

while q1.lower() in {"yes", "no"}:
    print ("Sorry but you answered \"" + q1 + "\" which means you lose!")
    sys.exit ("\nGame Over")

if q1 in accepted:
    print ("Well done you have earned yourself a point")
    score +=1
    print ("Your current score is: " + score)
```

Of course, if you count good answers, you will want to put this into some loop, then the initializition of `accepted` can stay outside.

Comment: I think you mean "You lose".

Comment: TY for the comment but I'm a bit OCD and would rather the library be a completely different text file otherwise I think that it looks messy and ruins the code. The help is still appreciated though.

Comment: @Ben That is just as easy. If each line in your text file corresponds to an accepted answer, you should initialize `lib` with `lib=set(line.strip() for line in open('library.txt'))` instead of the line in the code above.